How to fix the error generated by VertexStyle in the otpions of my graph plot
I aim to plot a  graph using the following code:
vertices={"S","I","R","S+I","2I","3I", "2S","I+R","I+2R","I+2S","0"};
groups={{"S","I","R"},{"S+I","2I","3I", "2S", "I+R","I+2R","I+2S"},{"0"}};
colors=Flatten@MapThread[Thread@*Rule,{groups,{Green,Red,Pink}}];
edges={Style[Labeled["0"->"S",\[CapitalLambda]],Black,Thick],Style[Labeled["I"->"R",Subscript[\[Gamma],i] i],Black,Thick],
Style[Labeled["R"->"S",(Subscript[\[Gamma],"r"])r],Black,Thick],Style[Labeled["S"->"R",Subscript[\[Gamma],s] s],Black,Thick],
Style[Labeled["S+I"->"2I",\[Beta] si],Black,Thick],Style[Labeled["S+I"->"I+2S",\[Delta] si],Black,Thick],
 Style[Labeled["S"->"0",\[Mu] s],Black,Thick],Style[Labeled["I+R"->"I+2R",\[Delta] ri],Black,Thick],
Style[Labeled["2I"->"3I",\[Delta] i^2],Black,Thick],
Style[Labeled["I"->"0",(\[Mu]+\[Delta]) i],Black,Thick],
Style[Labeled["R"->"0",\[Mu] r],Black,Thick]};

options={VertexLabels->{_->Placed[Automatic,Center]},
VertexShapeFunction->{"S"->"Square","I"->"Square","R"->"Square","0"->"ConcaveHexagon"},VertexStyle->colors,
VertexShapeFunction->({EdgeForm[Black],Disk[#1,0.1],Text[#2,#1]}&),VertexSize->Large,
ImageSize->400,PerformanceGoal->"Quality",EdgeLabelStyle->Directive[10,Background->White]}
flow=LayeredGraphPlot[edges,options,PlotStyle->{"TemperatureMap",Bold}]

But the output circumvents an error related to
VertexStyle->colors

When I remove the latter, I obtain an uncolored graph, but I would like to restore the colors.
I will be very grateful for any help.
Thanks.

There is not vertex "2S" in your graph, removing it from colors will solve the error. (or maybe adding that missing vertex to the graph).

Silly mistake. Thank you so much!
